# Including a custom file in your build/publish for a .net core application

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, msbuild

How do I include a custom file that is in the root of my project dir to be put into my build/publish folder?

If its a .json file it seems to come through automatically (probably because of .NET config being json)

I have a custom config file that is text based with a .txt extension.

I've tried:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotnetPublishFiles Include="customfile.txt"></DotnetPublishFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

And

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="./*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

As well as

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="customfile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also:

```
<_CustomFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/customfile.txt" />
    <DotNetPublishFiles Include="@(_CustomFiles)">
    </DotNetPublishFiles>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Nothing seems to work...

I'm using Visual Studio Code and .NET Core 3.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: did u ever get something to work? neither of the answers work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="customfile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

JSON (as well as other suitable) files are treated the same way by SDK style projects, so for your own custom files you need to ask MSBuild explicitly.

Comment: doesnt work for me in bazor trying to deploy sqllite file

Comment: i also note the XML is not well formed. Is this what you think should work? or an example taken from a working project file?

Answer (score 1):

For publishing there is another tag: CopyToPublishDirectory

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="customfile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  <ItemGroup>
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me (publishing to azure)